# Remove a character from string

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, cut

I'm simply trying to remove a `%` sign from a variable, so I may perform mathmatic calculations on the result. I've tried several things, but none of them seem to work:

```
$ output="23%"
# usep=$(echo $output | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d '%' -f 1)
# usep=`echo $output | sed 's/\%//g`
# usep=`echo $output | head -c 2`
```

The variable `usep` still contains the `%` character. Any ideas?

Comment: it looks like you're just trying random commands with no understanding of what each command does. Read the man page for each so you can understand them, and then don't use any of them but see Ruben's answer instead. Also, given what you posted above, I guarantee you're doing the wrong thing in the rest of your script wrt "mathmatic calculation" so post that if you'd like help.

Answer (score 6):

You may use POSIX parameter substitution:

```
$ output="23%"
$ usep=${output%%\%}
$ echo $usep
23
```

Comment: Definitely the best answer. No need to use external tools.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Bash substitutions for life! (:

Comment: FWIW - That is POSIX parameter substitution.  Any POSIX-compliant shell will have it - ksh has it for example.  See: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02

Comment: @jimmcnamara I'm not an expert on these formalities; as I have bash for shell, everything is bash for me, which is wrong, I agree, and so I thank you for the warning! (: I'll try to use some other shell, and something other than ubuntu ^^ Any recommendations?

Comment: You can get zsh, which does a few things very much unlike bash does them. It has built in time arithmetic. bash does not - bash uses the date command for that.

Comment: Nice, I'll try zsh! Any recommendations on an operating system other than a ubuntu/mint?

Comment: @bvukelic I'll be trying this out! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Rubens: In that case, make sure you read the install instructions thoroughly, and brace yourself for major sexiness. :)

Answer (score 2):

Assign `output` as

```
output="23%"
```

and you missed the second `'` in

```
usep=`echo $output | sed 's/%//g'`
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why the approach using `cut` didn't work for you, but here's one that works perfectly for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

output="23%"
usep=`echo $output | cut -d '%' -f 1`
echo $usep
```